# Trying to find particular data in one Excel spreadsheet, transfer it to another Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I have 2 spreadsheets in excel.  "Spreadsheet A" has ~ 1000 rows- each a different patient. "Column A" w/ name of patients and then "Column B" w/ age, "Column C" with medical record number etc.  I am adding new data to "Spreadsheet A"- tumor size in "Column BR").
"Spreadsheet B" has about 80% of the patients from "Spreadsheet A" (plus about 500 others).  It also has the tumor size data.  I am looking for a way to search by name ("Column A") for the patients in "Spreadsheet A" in "Spreadsheet B", and then when it finds a patient that is in both Spreadsheets, automatically insert the tumor size in "Column BR" in "Spreadsheet A" from "Spreadsheet B".

Answer (score 0):

You need the VLOOKUP function.  Have a look at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

This should work :

```
vlookup($A1,SheetB!$A$1:$J$500,10,false);
```

Be aware that :

- the names in A1 must be written exactly like the names in sheet B.
- the names in sheet B must be sorted.
- the number 10 (third parameter) in the above formula is a reference to the column number in the array $A$1:$J$500.  For that particular case it is column J.